# how to add float attribute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi guys im litte confuse. Im getting error

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'compound'
```

But for similar things on same model i didn't get.
This is my DF

```
Text    Tweet_tokenized Tweet_nonstop   Tweet_stemmed   sentiment   sentiment_rat2  neg neu pos compound
0   0   RT @bennyjohnson:  BOMBSHELL \n\nVeteran &am... [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshell, veteran, amp, bu...   [rt, bennyjohnson, bombshel, veteran, amp, bus...   (0.0, 0.07142857142857142)  Neutral 0.00    1.000   0.000   0.0000
```

And this is my code:

```
def polarity_sorterVAD(value):
    if value.compound >= 0.05:
        return "Postivie"
    elif -0.05 < value.compound < 0.05:
        return "Neutral"
    else: 
        return "Negative"

df['sentiment_rat3'] = df['compound'].apply(polarity_sorterVAD)
```

When i edited value.compound to df['compound'] i get

```
 The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Can you put an example on where you get the error and where you don't get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're doing apply on series, not on dataframe.

```
df['sentiment_rat3'] = df['compound'].apply(polarity_sorterVAD)
```

Here, df['compound'] is a series. When you pass this to your function  polarity_sorterVAD you're already passing the values of df['compound']

You can quickly check what values you're passing to apply function via print -

```
def polarity_sorterVAD(value):
    print(value)
```

So, you don't need to add value.compound here. Just value will work :)

Comment: So just need put if value <0.05 return negative ? that's it ? :) thanks

Comment: yup probably. Check the value that you're passing with print statement